# add gcc to system root image

Tags: gcc, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to add gcc package to the root file system by adding snippet code below on `/poky/meta-qti-bsp/recipies-products/images/BASE_IMAGE.inc`

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "packagegroup-core-buildessential"
```

`/poky/build/conf/local.conf`

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "tools-sdk dev-pkgs"
```

However I got error below

```
BUILD errors are as following: 
update-alternatives: Error: cannot register alternative cmp to /bin/cmp since it is already registered to /usr/bin/cmp

update-alternatives: Error: cannot register alternative groups to /usr/bin/groups since it is already registered to /bin/groups

update-alternatives: Error: cannot register alternative passwd to /usr/bin/passwd since it is already registered to /bin/passwd
Configuring perl-module-unupdate-alternatives: Error: cannot register alternative patch to /usr/bin/patch since it is already registered to /bin/patch
update-alternatives: Error: cannot register alternative readprofile to /usr/sbin/readprofile since it is already registered to /sbin/readprofile.
.
.
.
ERROR: Multilib check error: duplicate files poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/../../1.0-r0/multilib/lib32/usr/include/fpu_control.h /poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/../../1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/include/fpu_control.h is not the same
```

The `multilib_sanity` check function is trying to throw an error since there are both the files with 32 and 64 bits. I need to consider the 32 bit since my target is 32 bit.

How do I set this up so that only one among the files in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set your machine type correctly in local.conf. Then it would automatically pick either 32bit or 64bit files.